# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin x - \cos^{-1}(e^{-\frac{x^4}{2}})}{x^2} =$?

Tags: limits

Consider $f(x) = x - \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = \cos^{-1}(e^{-\frac{x^4}{2}})$
then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - g(x)}{x^2}$ = ?

This is a question from a college entrance exam practice workbook.
I tried using L Hospital's Rule, which simplifies it a bit to get me to $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^4}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^4}}}$
But after this I get stuck again.

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{{x^2 e^{ - x^4 /2} }}{{\sqrt {1 - e^{ - x^4 } } }} = \sqrt {\frac{{x^4 }}{{e^{x^4 }  - 1}}} 
$$

Comment: This expression will become 1, so the entire expression should become -1/2? But the answer given in my book is -1, so did I do something wrong in a previous step then?

Comment: That could be the case. I did not check that. Why don't you use Taylor polynomials?

Comment: We haven't been introduced to the concept of Taylor polynomials as it isn't in the syllabus of this particular entrance exams. So I'd like to avoid using them

Comment: Oh wait, never mind, I found the mistake in my previous step. Incorrectly wrote $\frac{1-cosx}{x} $ as 1 instead of 0. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is what I just got.

Comment: Hey there @Gary , I just found out that leaving questions like this with the answer in the comment is frowned upon. So would you like to elaborate on your hint and make it an answer, want me to answer this myself or something else entirely?

Comment: I think you can post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the answer based on @Gary 's hint (see comments)

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin x - \cos^{-1}(e^{-\frac{x^4}{2}})}{x^2}$$

Apply L Hospital's Rule,
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x-\frac{e^{-\frac{x^4}{2}}.2x^3}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^4}}}}{2x} $$
Splitting the fraction,
$$ = \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right).\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^2.e^{-\frac{x^4}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^4}}}$$

The first part is a standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} = 0$. For the second part, express the numerator as a square root.
$$= \lim_{x \to 0}0 - \sqrt{\frac{x^4.e^{-x^4}}{1-e^{-x^4}}}$$
Divide numerator and denominator by $e^{-x^4}$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} - \sqrt{\frac{x^4}{e^{x^4}-1}}$$
If you write $x^4 = t$,
$$=\lim_{t \to 0} - \sqrt{\frac{t}{e^t-1}}$$
Which is again a standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$,
$$ = -1$$